# How can I duplicate the if condition through foreach?

Tags: php

Is there anyone who knows to duplicate a IF CONDITION through looping? Please. I really need your help.. This is my first time to encounter thing like this? Help will be appreciated thanks.

```
<?php            
  for($x=0; $fetchImageDirectoryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchImageDirectory); $x++){
    $directory = $fetchImageDirectoryRow['Image_Path'];
    list($c, $apache24, $htdocs, $sp, $uploadItem, $imageFilename) = explode('/', $directory);
    $uploadItem = $uploadItem."/".$imageFilename; 

    $imageGet = glob($uploadItem);
    foreach($imageGet as $imagePath){
      $attName = uniqid();

      echo '<td>';
      echo "<img src= '".$imagePath."' class='readyToPostImage'/><br><br>";
      echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter New Price (eg. 300)' class='newPriceInput'/><br><br>";
      echo "<a class='addMore'>add more photos</a>";
      echo "<input type='file' class='browseCustom' multiple/><br>";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='".$attName."' class='btn btn-success' value='Post to Peónline'/>";
      echo '</td>';
```

How can I duplicate this IF Condition? Is there a function to copy the statement through looping.

```
      if(isset($_POST[$attName])){
      mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE collateral c LEFT JOIN loan_assignment a ON (a.item_id = c.item_id) LEFT JOIN pawnshop b ON (a.pawnshop_id = b.pawnshop_id) SET c.post_status = '1' where status_type = 'FORECLOSED' and  b.email_address = '".$login_session."' and image_path = '".$directory."';");
      mysqli_close($connection);
      }
    }
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking.  But a user fuction kind of sounds like what you may want

Comment: when I loop there, there would be a field for something then there should be a unique $_POST[$attName] and when I click the button the conditon will be executed

Comment: dont understand your question, what do you exactly mean by duplicate  ??

Comment: when foreach go through I want to have the same :if(isset($_POST[$attName])){
      mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE collateral c LEFT JOIN loan_assignment a ON (a.item_id = c.item_id) LEFT JOIN pawnshop b ON (a.pawnshop_id = b.pawnshop_id) SET c.post_status = '1' where status_type = 'FORECLOSED' and  b.email_address = '".$login_session."' and image_path = '".$directory."';");
      mysqli_close($connection);
      }